# strange error 'unrecognized selector sent to instance'

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm having an error when trying to pass a bunch of variables from one class to another, my first class controls one view, and my other class is a tableviewcontroller that controls a table view, I have a segue named "shoplistSegue" and when I click one button it performs the segue and pass variables using "prepareForSegue" method. but when I click the button it freezes and an error appears "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x74af950".

class1.h

```
@interface CalcularViewController : UIViewController{

    int calcularIntHomens;
    int calcularIntMulheres;
    int calcularIntCriancas;

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *calcularLabelHomens;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *calcularLabelMulheres;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *calcularLabelCriancas;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *calcularLabelFantasmas;
@property int calcularIntHomens;
@property int calcularIntMulheres;
@property int calcularIntCriancas;
- (IBAction)subtractHomens:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)subtractMulheres:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)subtractCriancas:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addHomens:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addMulheres:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addCriancas:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)showResultsIfNotNull:(id)sender;

@end
```

class1.m

```
#import "CalcularViewController.h"
#import "ResultadoViewController.h"

@interface CalcularViewController ()

@end

@implementation CalcularViewController
@synthesize calcularIntCriancas, calcularIntHomens, calcularIntMulheres, calcularLabelCriancas, calcularLabelHomens, calcularLabelMulheres, calcularLabelFantasmas;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)subtractHomens:(id)sender {

    if (calcularIntHomens > 0) {
    calcularIntHomens = calcularIntHomens -1;
    NSString *submen = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", calcularIntHomens];
    calcularLabelHomens.text = submen;
    }

}
- (IBAction)subtractMulheres:(id)sender{

    if (calcularIntMulheres > 0) {
    calcularIntMulheres = calcularIntMulheres -1;
    NSString *subwoman = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", calcularIntMulheres];
    calcularLabelMulheres.text = subwoman;
    }

}
- (IBAction)subtractCriancas:(id)sender{

    if (calcularIntCriancas > 0) {
    calcularIntCriancas = calcularIntCriancas -1;
    NSString *subchild = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", calcularIntCriancas];
    calcularLabelCriancas.text = subchild;
    }
}
- (IBAction)addCriancas:(id)sender{

    calcularIntCriancas = calcularIntCriancas +1;
    NSString *addchild = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", calcularIntCriancas];
    calcularLabelCriancas.text = addchild;
}
- (IBAction)addHomens:(id)sender{

    calcularIntHomens = calcularIntHomens +1;
    NSString *addmen = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", calcularIntHomens];
    calcularLabelHomens.text = addmen;
}
- (IBAction)addMulheres:(id)sender{

    calcularIntMulheres = calcularIntMulheres +1;
    NSString *addwoman = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", calcularIntMulheres];
    calcularLabelMulheres.text = addwoman;
}

-(IBAction)showResultsIfNotNull:(id)sender{

    if (calcularIntHomens == 0) {
        if (calcularIntMulheres == 0) {
            if (calcularIntCriancas == 0) {
                calcularLabelFantasmas.text = @"Você vai fazer um churrasco pra fantasmas?";
            } else {
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"resultadoSegue" sender:self];
            }
        } else {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"resultadoSegue" sender:self];

        }
    } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"resultadoSegue" sender:self];

    }

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"resultadoSegue"]) {

        ResultadoViewController *resultados = [segue destinationViewController];

        resultados.resultadoIntCriancas = calcularIntCriancas;
        resultados.resultadoIntHomens = calcularIntHomens;
        resultados.resultadoIntMulheres = calcularIntMulheres;

    }
}
@end
```

class2.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ResultadoViewController : UIViewController{

    int resultadoIntHomens;
    int resultadoIntMulheres;
    int resultadoIntCriancas;
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
    float resultadoGado;
    float resultadoFrango;
    float resultadoPorco;
    float resultadoLinguica;
    float resultadoQueijo;
    float resultadoPaodealho;
    float resultadoAcompanhamento;
    float resultadoAbacaxiassado;
    float resultadoCebolaassada;
    float resultadoBebidas;
    float resultadoAlcool;
    int areThereBebidas;
    BOOL picanhaBOOL;
    BOOL alcatraBOOL;
    BOOL maminhaBOOL;
    BOOL contrafileBOOL;
    BOOL lombinhoBOOL;
    BOOL linguicaBOOL;
    BOOL coracaoBOOL;
    BOOL asaBOOL;
    BOOL coxaBOOL;
    BOOL queijoBOOL;
    BOOL paodealhoBOOL;
    BOOL arrozBOOL;
    BOOL farofaBOOL;
    BOOL vinagreteBOOL;
    BOOL maionesesaladaBOOL;
    BOOL saladaBOOL;
    BOOL abacaxiassadoBOOL;
    BOOL cebolaBOOL;
    BOOL cervejaBOOL;
    BOOL refriBOOL;
    BOOL aguaBOOL;
    BOOL vodkaBOOL;
    BOOL sucoBOOL;
    int gadoTotal;
    int frangoTotal;
    int acompanhamentoTotal;
    int bebidaTotal;
    int something;
    int alcoolTotal;


}
@property int alcoolTotal;
@property int areThereBebidas;
@property float resultadoAlcool;
@property int resultadoIntHomens;
@property int resultadoIntMulheres;
@property int resultadoIntCriancas;
@property float resultadoGado;
@property float resultadoFrango;
@property float resultadoPorco;
@property float resultadoLinguica;
@property float resultadoQueijo;
@property float resultadoPaodealho;
@property float resultadoAcompanhamento;
@property float resultadoAbacaxiassado;
@property float resultadoCebolaassada;
@property float resultadoBebidas;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultadoLabelPicanha;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultadoLabelAlcatra;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultadoLabelMaminha;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultadoLabelContrafile;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultadoLabelLombinho;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultadoLabelLinguica;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultadoLabelCoracao;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultadoLabelAsa;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultadoLabelCoxa;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultadoLabelQueijo;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultadoLabelPaodealho;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultadoLabelArroz;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultadoLabelFarofa;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultadoLabelVinagrete;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultadoLabelSaladamaionese;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultadoLabelSalada;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultadoLabelAbacaxiassado;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultadoLabelCebola;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultadoLabelCerveja;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultadoLabelRefri;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultadoLabelAgua;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultadoLabelVodka;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultadoLabelSuco;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultadoLabelFome;
- (IBAction)addPicanha:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addAlcatra:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addMaminha:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addContrafile:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addLombinho:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addLinguica:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addCoracao:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addAsa:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addCoxa:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addQueijo:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addPaodealho:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addArroz:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addFarofa:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addVinagrete:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addSaladamaionese:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addSalada:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addAbacaxi:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)AddCebola:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addCerveja:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addRefri:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addAgua:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addVodka:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addSuco:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)buttonBack:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)buttonNext:(id)sender;
@property BOOL picanhaBOOL;
@property BOOL alcatraBOOL;
@property BOOL maminhaBOOL;
@property BOOL contrafileBOOL;
@property BOOL lombinhoBOOL;
@property BOOL linguicaBOOL;
@property BOOL coracaoBOOL;
@property BOOL asaBOOL;
@property BOOL coxaBOOL;
@property BOOL queijoBOOL;
@property BOOL paodealhoBOOL;
@property BOOL arrozBOOL;
@property BOOL farofaBOOL;
@property BOOL vinagreteBOOL;
@property BOOL maionesesaladaBOOL;
@property BOOL saladaBOOL;
@property BOOL abacaxiassadoBOOL;
@property BOOL cebolaBOOL;
@property BOOL cervejaBOOL;
@property BOOL refriBOOL;
@property BOOL aguaBOOL;
@property BOOL vodkaBOOL;
@property BOOL sucoBOOL;
@property int gadoTotal;
@property int frangoTotal;
@property int acompanhamentoTotal;
@property int bebidaTotal;
@property int something;


@end
```

class2.m

```
#import "ResultadoViewController.h"
#import "ShoplistViewController.h"

@interface ResultadoViewController ()

@end

@implementation ResultadoViewController
@synthesize resultadoIntCriancas, resultadoIntHomens, resultadoIntMulheres, resultadoAbacaxiassado, resultadoAcompanhamento, resultadoBebidas, resultadoCebolaassada, resultadoFrango, resultadoGado, resultadoLinguica, resultadoPaodealho, resultadoPorco, resultadoQueijo, resultadoLabelAbacaxiassado, resultadoLabelAgua, resultadoLabelAlcatra, resultadoLabelArroz, resultadoLabelAsa, resultadoLabelCebola, resultadoLabelCerveja, resultadoLabelContrafile, resultadoLabelCoracao, resultadoLabelCoxa, resultadoLabelFarofa, resultadoLabelFome, resultadoLabelLinguica, resultadoLabelLombinho, resultadoLabelMaminha, resultadoLabelPaodealho, resultadoLabelPicanha, resultadoLabelQueijo, resultadoLabelRefri, resultadoLabelSalada, resultadoLabelSaladamaionese, resultadoLabelSuco, resultadoLabelVinagrete, resultadoLabelVodka, picanhaBOOL, alcatraBOOL, lombinhoBOOL, contrafileBOOL, maminhaBOOL, linguicaBOOL, coracaoBOOL, queijoBOOL, asaBOOL, coxaBOOL, paodealhoBOOL, arrozBOOL, farofaBOOL, vinagreteBOOL, saladaBOOL, maionesesaladaBOOL, abacaxiassadoBOOL, cebolaBOOL, cervejaBOOL, refriBOOL, aguaBOOL, sucoBOOL, vodkaBOOL, gadoTotal, something, frangoTotal, acompanhamentoTotal, bebidaTotal, resultadoAlcool, areThereBebidas, alcoolTotal;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1035)];


    UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    backButton.frame     = CGRectMake(20, 986, 108, 30);
    [backButton setTitle:@"Voltar" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonBack:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [scroller addSubview:backButton];

    UIButton *nextButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    nextButton.frame     = CGRectMake(192, 986, 108, 30);
    [nextButton setTitle:@"Continuar..." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [nextButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonNext:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [scroller addSubview:nextButton];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    gadoTotal = 0;

    something = 0;

    resultadoGado = resultadoIntHomens * 0.400 + resultadoIntMulheres * 0.355 + resultadoIntCriancas * 0.200;

    resultadoLinguica = resultadoIntHomens * 0.070 + resultadoIntMulheres * 0.050 + resultadoIntCriancas * 0.030;

    resultadoPorco = resultadoIntHomens * 0.060 + resultadoIntMulheres * 0.035 + resultadoIntCriancas * 0.030;

    resultadoFrango = resultadoIntHomens *  0.085 + resultadoIntMulheres * 0.055 + resultadoIntCriancas * 0.042;

    resultadoQueijo = resultadoIntHomens *  0.050 + resultadoIntMulheres * 0.040 + resultadoIntCriancas * 0.020;

    resultadoAcompanhamento = resultadoIntHomens *  0.225 + resultadoIntMulheres * 0.190 + resultadoIntCriancas * 0.100;

    resultadoAbacaxiassado = resultadoIntHomens *  0.040 + resultadoIntMulheres * 0.025 + resultadoIntCriancas * 0.020;

    resultadoCebolaassada = resultadoIntHomens *  0.050 + resultadoIntMulheres * 0.035 + resultadoIntCriancas * 0.020;

    resultadoPaodealho = resultadoIntHomens *  0.070 + resultadoIntMulheres * 0.045 + resultadoIntCriancas * 0.030;

    resultadoAlcool = resultadoIntHomens *  0.600 + resultadoIntMulheres * 0.350 + resultadoIntCriancas * 0.000;

    resultadoBebidas = resultadoIntHomens *  0.500 + resultadoIntMulheres * 0.650 + resultadoIntCriancas * 0.700;



    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)buttonBack:(id)sender{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"backtoCalcSegue" sender:self];

}

-(IBAction)buttonNext:(id)sender{

    if (gadoTotal > 0){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"shoplistSegue" sender:self];
}else { resultadoLabelFome.text = @"Assim as pessoas vão morrer de fome!";}

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"shoplistSegue"]) {

        ShoplistViewController *resultados = [segue destinationViewController];

        resultados.shoplistPicanha = [resultadoLabelPicanha.text floatValue];
        resultados.shoplistAlcatra = [resultadoLabelAlcatra.text floatValue];
        resultados.shoplistMaminha = [resultadoLabelMaminha.text floatValue];
        resultados.shoplistContrafile = [resultadoLabelContrafile.text floatValue];
        resultados.shoplistLombinho = [resultadoLabelLombinho.text floatValue];
        resultados.shoplistLinguica = [resultadoLabelLinguica.text floatValue];
        resultados.shoplistAsa = [resultadoLabelAsa.text floatValue];
        resultados.shoplistCoxa = [resultadoLabelCoxa.text floatValue];
        resultados.shoplistCoracao = [resultadoLabelCoracao.text floatValue];
        resultados.shoplistQueijo = [resultadoLabelQueijo.text floatValue];
        resultados.shoplistPaodealho = [resultadoLabelPaodealho.text floatValue];
        resultados.shoplistArroz = [resultadoLabelArroz.text floatValue];
        resultados.shoplistFarofa = [resultadoLabelFarofa.text floatValue];
        resultados.shoplistVinagrete = [resultadoLabelVinagrete.text floatValue];
        resultados.shoplistMaionese = [resultadoLabelSaladamaionese.text floatValue];
        resultados.shoplistSalada = [resultadoLabelSalada.text floatValue];
        resultados.shoplistAbacaxi = [resultadoLabelAbacaxiassado.text floatValue];
        resultados.shoplistCebola = [resultadoLabelCebola.text floatValue];
        resultados.shoplistAgua = [resultadoLabelAgua.text floatValue];
        resultados.shoplistCerveja = [resultadoLabelCerveja.text floatValue];
        resultados.shoplistRefri = [resultadoLabelRefri.text floatValue];
        resultados.shoplistVodka = [resultadoLabelVodka.text floatValue];
        resultados.shoplistSuco = [resultadoLabelSuco.text floatValue];

    }
}

@end
```

EDIT:

it was working properly until i deleted the destination view and put it there again cause it had a little problem on interface builder. When I put it there, on the inspector i put the controlling class againg and everything it had before again...

Comment: what is the exact error message, including stack trace?

Comment: sorry, i'm new on development... what's a stack trace?

Comment: it is in 99% of the cases (999 questions here on SO -- at least) caused by sending a message to a released object

Comment: just besides the `unrecognized selector sent to instance` you should read more information about the selector and the actual class ot the object it was sent to...

Comment: it appears like thins on my output:

2013-01-31 13:33:59.575 O Churrasco![84255:c07] Warning: Attempt to present <ResultadoViewController: 0x84c28f0> on <CalcularViewController: 0x84bab10> while a presentation is in progress!
2013-01-31 13:34:03.434 O Churrasco![84255:c07] -[UITableViewController setShoplistPicanha:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x74cbe70
2013-01-31 13:34:03.435 O Churrasco![84255:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewController setShoplistPicanha:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x74cbe70'

Comment: *** First throw call stack:
(0x1f0d012 0x134ae7e 0x1f984bd 0x1efcbbc 0x1efc94e 0x25baa6 0x6d6b87 0x370dd2 0xdbe012c 0x475d 0x135e705 0x2922c0 0x292258 0x353021 0x35357f 0x3526e8 0x2c1cef 0x2c1f02 0x29fd4a 0x291698 0x1e68df9 0x1e68ad0 0x1e82bf5 0x1e82962 0x1eb3bb6 0x1eb2f44 0x1eb2e1b 0x1e677e3 0x1e67668 0x28effc 0x273d 0x2665)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: Add the stack trace to your question. Putting it in comments is awkward.

Comment: What is setShoplistPicanha? Could you show the code where this is called? supposed to be? it seems to be the problem.

Comment: parece que vc esta chamando um metodo que nao é alvo. Ou seja, o metodo esta escrito de forma errada ao chamar, ou ele nao existe, ou vc esta colocando : sendo que nao existe parametro

Comment: Cheque se esta acao do botao deste metodo setShoplistPicanha esta sendo chamada devidamente. Se nao estiver conseguindo resolver, de um upload no seu codigo que posso ajudar.

Comment: thanks, I found out what was my mistake, @JuanMunhoesJunior thank you, I was really what you said, I was calling a class that had a typo on the name... Thank you all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"shoplistSegue"]) {

    ShoplistViewController *resultados = [segue destinationViewController];

    resultados.shoplistPicanha = [resultadoLabelPicanha.text floatValue];
```

Either `ShoplistViewController` doesn't implement `-setShoplistPicanha:` / has no `@property (readwrite) shopListPicanha`
or your `[segue destinationViewController]` doesn't return what you think it does (ie not
a ShoplistViewController).

Answer (score 0):

You try to call

```
 UITableViewController  setShoplistPicanha:
```

and apparently it is not defined (with one argument)

Comment: The person who down voted my answer should read the accepted answer and at least provide an explanation for the down vote.

Comment: Voted it up. OP (and many others) needs to learn the basic technique of reading an error message. What you say is exactly what the error message said. The next step is not to be confused by the information, but to check where setShoplistPicanha is called, or where someobject.shoplistPicanha is set. And then you see an object set to the result of destinationViewController which returns an id, so there is no type checking, and that's most likely the culprit.